# Produce an OpenType font programmatically: request for HOWTO

Tags: build, fonts, svg, automation, opentype

Background: Adobe released their first open source fonts to the GitHub. Repos consist of many files with different syntax, some of them are binary. See e.g. https://github.com/adobe/source-sans-pro

In the corresponding README file, build process is outlined like this:

*> Key to building OTF or TTF fonts is `makeotf`, which is part of the AFDKO toolset.*
*> In this repository, all necessary files are in place for building the OTF and TTF fonts.*

It works, but doesn't contribute to my understanding of the font creation process. I've found specs of some of the formats, but very little about what they do. A good HOWTO would help a lot.

And the main question is, **I have glyphs in SVG** (or any other vector) format and necessary metrics for each glyph. Let's also say that kerning is a non-issue for now, to keep things simple.

**How do I build an OTF** (or TTF) font file automatically with those?

I'm comfortable with both programming and reading the f. manuals, just don't know where to begin.